# What's the correct treatment of widows of slain soldiers and Kings in a battle?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, war

When an ārya defeats his opponent in a battle, what's the correct treatment to be metted out to the women of opponent as per scriptures?

2nd part: Are the rules of treating womenfolk of defeated party different if the latter were mlechhas?